# Tnsnames not found in python even thou its set in env variables on win

Tags: python, database, oracle, tnsnames

I have a seemingly simple issue.
When trying to connect to oracle database with python script it throws me this error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

The thing is that tnsnames.ora is set in TNS_ADMIN environmental variable (im working on win 10) and I can even find it via sqldeveloper when creating new connections. Furthermore, Im sure im using correct dsn in my script ... hence... any ideas?

Comment: by the way, have you tried "tnsping <db_alias>" from the "cmd"?

Comment: Should you be using the SERVICE_NAME attribute instead of the long obsolete SID attribute in your tnsnames.ora file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my code. Hope it helps

```
self.mydsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.parser.get(
    'oracle', 'db'),
    self.parser.get('oracle', 'port'),
    self.parser.get('oracle', 'service_name')
    )
```

Comment: in the end I just did this:
cx_Oracle.connect("usr/pass@server:1521/sid") and it just worked. I trust your works too =]